# Horizontal scrollbar appears when viewport is decreased

Tags: html, css

I have a menu whose sub menu is causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear when the viewport is decreased.

Here is the css

```
.main-menu ul li > .sub-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

Right now the sub menu is floating right(i hope i used the right term). Will it be possible to just float the sub menu to left of its parent???

Here is the fiddle to reporduce the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/sk8m54g1/

As you can see in the image, the sub menu is extending to the right from its parent. What i want is, the sub menu to extend to the left from its parent.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue without `html`. It would help more if you can provide it.

Comment: i will create a fiddle@AkshayMilmile

Comment: yeah, that will do.

Comment: @AkshayM question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the left value. -40px or -35px.

```
.main-menu ul li > .sub-menu {
...
    left: -40px;
...
}
```